# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I am trying to learn Cython at the moment and have followed a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXuEoqK4bEc).

I have it working within Ubuntu (on vmware) but right now I am trying to get it working on windows (using VSCode). I took all the files that I had created in Ubuntu and put them on my machine.

When I try to run my python file testing.py I receive this error:
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'example_cy'

here is the code for the testing.py

```
import timeit

cy = timeit.timeit('example_cy.test(5000)', setup = 'import example_cy', number = 1000)
py = timeit.timeit('example_py.test(5000)', setup = 'import example_py', number = 1000)

print(cy, py)
print('Cython is {}x faster'.format(py/cy))
```

This is the example_cy.pyx file

```
cpdef int test(int x):
    cdef int y = 0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(x):
        y += i
    return y
```

The example_py.py file

```
def test(x):
    y = 0
    for i in range(x):
        y += i
    return y
```

and the setup.py code

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('example_cy.pyx'))
```

Comment: Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: @Michael Hofman Yeah they are

Comment: Have you actually run setup.py to produce your compiled module? And if you have, what command did you use?